# z-index not working with blur effect in styled component

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I am trying to use the blur effect in css to blur the background and z-index to stack the logo on the blurred image but the same is not happening my logo is down under the blurred background.Please let me know the issue.
Styled component heirarchy:

```
    <LandingPageContainer>
      <Background />
      <LandingPageContentContainer>
        <Logo src={piattoLogo} />
        <ContentContainer>
          <Content>Premium handcrafted delicacies</Content>
          <Button>Lets go!</Button>
        </ContentContainer>
      </LandingPageContentContainer>
    </LandingPageContainer>
```

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

import landingBackground from '../../../../../img/piatto/CustomerLanding/CustomerLanding.jpg';

export const LandingPageContainer = styled.div`
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 812px;
  background-color: #0d0c0c;
`;

export const Background = styled.div`
  width: 390px;
  height: 526px;
  left: -326px;
  top: -80px;
  filter: blur(2px);
  background: url(${landingBackground}) no-repeat center center/cover;
`;

export const LandingPageContentContainer = styled.div`
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  padding: auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: -130px;
  z-index: 2;
`;

export const Logo = styled.img`
  width: 201px;
  height: 164px;
`;


`;
```

Comment: It'd be great to see actual HTML and CSS, but from what I can see, you are either missing `position: relative` on `LandingPageContainer` and `LandingPageContentContainer`, and it's possible that the `Background`'s `blur()`, which usually creates a new stacking context, is either on a new layer, or is changing the paint order.

Comment: Hey..Thanks! Position attribute was the issue..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember `z-index` only works on positioned elements (relative, absolute, sticky, fixed).